# How to pass value from Lightning Web Component to Flow variable?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Does anyone know the way to pass value from LWC to Flow variable?

When clicking "Add Name" button, I want input value to be passed to Flow valuable. "Manually assign variables (advanced)" is valid on the screen setting. But the variable is null and never changes.

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>50.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__FlowScreen</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__FlowScreen">
            <property name="sampleName" type="String" label="sampleName"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

js

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';
import { FlowAttributeChangeEvent, FlowNavigationNextEvent } from 'lightning/flowSupport';
export default class sampleFlowComponent extends LightningElement {
    @api
    availableActions = [];
    @api
    sampleName;
    handleAttributeChange() {
        const attributeChangeEvent = new FlowAttributeChangeEvent('sampleName', this.sampleName);
        this.dispatchEvent(attributeChangeEvent);
    }
    handleNext() {
        if (this.availableActions.find(action => action === 'NEXT')) {
            const navigateNextEvent = new FlowNavigationNextEvent();
            this.dispatchEvent(navigateNextEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

html

```
<template>
    <lightning-input
        label="sampleName"
        type="text">
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-button
        label="Add Name"
        title="Add Name"
        onclick={handleAttributeChange}>
    </lightning-button>
    <lightning-button
        label="Go Next"
        title="Go next"
        onclick={handleNext}>
    </lightning-button>
</template>
```

Any information would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Add an `onchange` handler to the input to call:

```
onchange(event){
    this.sampleName= event.target.value; 
}
```

No need of a specific button.